# How do I make a reaction roles command?

Tags: python, bots, pycord

```
@bot.slash_command(name="rr")
async def rr_setup(ctx, message_link: str, role: discord.Role, emoji: str,
                   dm: str, dm_rem: str):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.respond("You don't have permissions for this command.", ephemeral=True)
        return

    try:
        message_id = message_link.split('/')[-1]
        message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message_id)

        if not message:
            await ctx.send("<:no__:974587445138038794> Incorrect syntax!", ephemeral=True)
            return

        await message.add_reaction(emoji)

        def check(reaction, user):
            return str(reaction.emoji) == str(emoji) and user != bot.user and reaction.message.id == message.id

        while True:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
            if role not in user.roles:
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await user.send(dm)

            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_remove', check=check)
            if role in user.roles:
                await user.remove_roles(role)
                await user.send(dm_rem)

        await ctx.respond("Successfully added reaction to role.", ephemeral=True)

    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.respond("<:no__:974587445138038794> Incorrect syntax!", ephemeral=True)
```

I want to create simple reaction roles in my bot. It currently adds reactions but when I react to this, it doesn't add the role to me. It doesn't show any errors either.

Comment: That's a very bad approach, especially using the `while True` loop here and checking for two events at the same time. Why not store the set roles/emojis in a JSON and then use the `on_raw_reaction_add/remove` event?

Comment: Are you using discord.py or pycord? Both are very different libraries and have very different approaches. You can't have both in tags.